# No puedo instalar la librería "axios" en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando instalar `axios` porque estoy llamando a una api pero es que me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fichero `api.js` en cuestión tiene el siguiente contenido (como veis, importo axios).

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast'
});
```

Adicionalmente, os adjunto una captura de lo que me pasa al hacer un `npm install axios`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os pongo también mi fichero package.json por si necesitáis ver información adicional.
¡Muchas gracias de antemano y que paséis un buen día!

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo varias cosas para que revises.

1.- Cierra todas los programas que tienes (el gestor de archivos también que el error que te da es porque no puede copiar la carpeta).

2.- La herramienta que utilices para descargar el paquete e instalarlo ejecútalo como administrador (para evita que tenga mas permisos)

3.- Si esto no funciona mira si tu antivirus tiene pillado algún archivo del programa (como prueba yo lo pararía y probaría a descargar e instalar de nuevo)

4.- Puedes probar a crear un proyecto e instalar solo la librería que te da problemas para ver si es error es instalación es solo de tu proyecto o se repite en mas proyectos.

5.- Por ultimo yo probaría a reiniciar el equipo entero alguna veces se quedan archivos sin cerrar y el problema es que no puede copiar una carpeta la de modules (seguramente la tengas abierta)